# TableViewSection.remove example

Tags: javascript, titanium

Does anyone know how to remove a row inside a TableView in Titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableview.deleteRow(0);
```

don't pass the row object, it wont work instead pass the index and it would. The doc is completely mess there.

Answer (score 3):

To remove from a TableView you can use `Ti.UI.TableView.deleteRow()`

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView.deleteRow-method.html

To remove from a TableViewSection you can use `Ti.UI.TableViewSection.remove()`

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewSection.remove-method.html

Answer (score 2):

It's in the documentation, as Brian Huenefeld pointed out, but it's also in the Kitchen Sink app

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/table_view_row_delete.js

In the future, please conduct a bit more due-diligence before asking questions